# Increase fuzzy shadow steps for tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, shadows

Is there a way to increase the number of steps for the fuzzy-shadow option of *tcolorbox*?

The shadow has about the size and feather-range I am looking for but seems a bit ragged.

Can the number of steps the fuzzy shadow uses be increased?

[image: Example]

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bgtan}{HTML}{F7F2E5}
\pagecolor{bgtan}

\newtcolorbox{paperbox}[1][]{
    frame hidden,
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0.25ex,
    arc=0mm,
    borderline north={1pt}{-0.5pt}{black},
    borderline south={1pt}{-0.5pt}{black},
    colback=black!20!white,
    colframe=black!20!white,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-4pt}{-0.5pt}{0.4mm}{black!60!white},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{paperbox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paperbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `0.2mm` instead of `0.4mm` is no option? You're using `-4pt` as vertical size, perhaps you should switch to `0.4pt` as step size to get 10 'shadows'

Comment: A `fuzzy shadow` consists of a fixed number of 10 simple `shadow` entities. As Christian Hupfer wrote, the step size can be made smaller to get a more smooth (but smaller) appearance. Another possibility would be to use a combination of several `shadow` options (more than 10) to create a smoother shadow.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: People might address you to provide a key etc. to remove the fixed number of shadows here  (well, people, not me ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Thomas F. Sturm in a comment to the original question the **number of shades** generated by `fuzzy shadow` is currently **fixed at 10**.

Generating more steps is possible by using multiple `shadow` enteties manually.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've understood the `step` argument of `fuzzy shadow` is a shrink offset and the vertical shift divided by the step size should give the number of individual shadows being drawn.

If the shift is given in `pt`, it's perhaps better to provide the same length unit for the step as well.

I've used `0.4pt` to provide for 10 'shadows':

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bgtan}{HTML}{F7F2E5}
\pagecolor{bgtan}

\newtcolorbox{paperbox}[1][]{
    frame hidden,
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0.25ex,
    arc=0mm,
    borderline north={1pt}{-0.5pt}{black},
    borderline south={1pt}{-0.5pt}{black},
    colback=black!20!white,
    colframe=black!20!white,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-4pt}{-0.5pt}{0.4pt}{black!60!white},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{paperbox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paperbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using units consistantly is a good hint but as far as I understand - also from the comments to my original question - this approach doesn't actually change the number of shades: It is always fixed at 10 - right?

Comment: @Cathode: Yes, I know now, but I had the impression that it had changed. Perhaps Thomas Sturm will update his package soon and this fixed number might be variable then